# Are Script Properties available to the client?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

With a file structure in Google Apps Script like:

- code.gs
- page.html

where code.gs serves page.html with `doGet`

Are the script properties available to the javascript inside the `<script>` tags in page.html?
If so, how would I access them?

- [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [client server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: PropertiesService only available on server side.  But you could the the entire object return to you with `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().functionName();`

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree w/ comment. There is probably no direct way, so this works ok.

```
// server-side
function getProperties(){
  const properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  return JSON.stringify(properties)
}

// client-side
function getPropertiesFromServer(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(processProperties).getProperties()
}
function processProperties(propertiesText){
  const properties = JSON.parse(propertiesText)
  ...
}
```

Comment:

> PropertiesService only available on server side. But you could the the entire object return to you with
> google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().functionName(); –  Cooper

Comment: Comments might be deleted at any time. If the referred comment is relevant, add it to the answer providing the proper attribution.